# Primefaces ring sliding

Tags: primefaces

Is there any way to sliding the primeface "ring" as we are done by jquery???

```
  <p:ring id="basic" value="#{user.userList}" var="player">
```

Above code sliding after click and rotate only one times.

Comment: to what jquery plugin are you comparing the primefaces ring exactly ?

Comment: then how about this ? http://www.primefaces.org/showcase/ui/galleria.jsf